# How can I make bootstrap modal changes reflect the specific input field I clicked on?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form where I have five text input fields. Every time I click on the input field, a bootstrap modal shows up, and the modal contains information about the value of the input field. This is the code that I have for when someone clicks on the input field:

```
$(input).on('click', function(){ 
   // do stuff
  $('#myModal).modal('show');
});
```

However, whenever I make changes in the modal itself, it does not reflect to that specific input field. This is the function I have

```
$('#myModal').on('change', function(){
   //do stuff
});
```

Could someone tell me how can I include a reference to the input field I just clicked on in the second function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this ?

```
var target = '';
$('input').on('click', function(){ 
    // do stuff
    target = $(this);
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
    return target;
});
$('#myModal').on('change', function(){
    //do stuff
    target.dostuff();
});
```